# Can I allow a specific PC only internet traffic in my home Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a LINKSYS WRT54G2 router in my home network. Can i set it up in a way that would allow me to specify a pc that should only send and receive internet traffic, and be blocked off completely from the rest of my network?

The reason is that i have a laptop that has been prone to viruses over the last couple of months, and i would like to at least have internet access (over wi-fi) while i troubleshoot the issues, but i want avoid any risks to the other devices on my network.

Comment: Which firmware are you using on the linksys? Asking because it theory you should be able to create multiple subnets and place your isolation PC in a separate subnet without routes to to the other local subnet. But the big question is if the default firmware allows this. (And if not if DD-WRT and friends are an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had exactly the same problem recently. I was unable to find a way to do this. However... it just so happened my router died (after a good 10+ years!). I replaced it with a Netgear, and the Netgear actually has what they call a "guest network", which is a whole separate WiFi SSID that it broadcasts, and is isolated from the primary (wired and wireless) network. Comes in quite in handy, that!

Comment: Netgear has lot of router models. You should mention which one is yours. @eidy

Comment: I was hoping to not have to buy a new router, as i'm pretty happy with my current one.

Comment: It's a WNDR3400. Sorry 'bout that. @David, I understand not wanting to buy new... I only did cuz my old Linksys died. But I was still putting it out there because if it comes down to it, this model seems to work well for that use. My old linksys was a WRT54G.